# Tmux, Nvim or Windows Terminal puts some lines on the wrong pane

Tags: tmux, neovim, windows-terminal, coc.nvim

I've been using nVim and tmux for a while now, but recently I've been having some problems. I seem to be getting some weird artifacts across my IDE which usually involve misplaced or duplicated lines.

Below, you can see an example of the problem:
[image: A screenshot of the problem. There are two panes created by tmux, with a vertical split between them. On the left side is some code and on the right is a jest testing console. For some reason though, some of the jest testing lines are being displayed on the side of the code and are showing blank on the correct side.]

On the left is some code of mine, and on the right is a Jest testing console. The vertical split is made with tmux and as you can see, on lines 2, 4, 15, 20, 22, 27, 29, 37 and lower, the content from the right pane is displaying on the left pane.

This is one example, but I also have been having problems with duplication of code etc.

Note, none of this code actually exists and I cannot select it. Sometimes I can get it to go away by going into `VISUAL BLOCK` mode and selecting the messed up lines. This doesn't always work though.

Has anybody else had this issue? I can't tell if the problem lies with tmux, nvim or windows terminal.

```
tmux version: 3.0a

NVIM version: 0.7.0-dev

Windows Terminal version: 1.13.11431.0
```

Hope somebody can help me!

Please and thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is tracked by

**Rendering errors in tmux split panes**:
[microsoft/terminal#6987](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6987)

Sorry I don't have a solution for that one yet